# Why is "hg push" so much bigger than .hg?

Tags: mercurial

My project's `.hg` directory is 40MB. If I `hg push --verbose --debug` to an empty remote repository I see it sending hundreds of MBs. Where is the extra overhead coming from?

**UPDATE**: `hg bundle -a` generates a 35MB file. Here is a stripped-down version of the output I'm seeing:

```
pushing to https://jace.googlecode.com/hg/
using https://jace.googlecode.com/hg/
sending between command
using auth.default.* for authentication
jace.googlecode.com certificate successfully verified
sending capabilities command
using auth.default.* for authentication
capabilities: branchmap lookup unbundle=HG10UN,HG10UGZ,HG10BZ changegroupsubset
sending heads command
using auth.default.* for authentication
searching for changes
common changesets up to 71818a195bf5
sending branchmap command
[...]
bundling: <filenames>
sending unbundle command
sending xxx bytes
[...]
sending: xxx/xxx kb
```

Comment: "I see it sending hundreds of MBs." -- How did you measure that?

Comment: @Joel, the output (posted above) says "sending xxx bytes" where xxx is 300MB or so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known python bug. Because of the way the python http library work, it first sends the data, the server replies that it needs an auth, and it resends the data.

With a recent mercurial (starting at 1.9) you can use an alternative http library. Just add the following in hgrc:

```
[ui]
usehttp2 = true
```

Comment: Very interesting! Can you please link to bug reports and discussions that shed more light on this?

Comment: I can't figure out how to enable this option. It's not clear where it's supposed to go in hgrc nor what version of Mercurial supports it.

Comment: This was released in 1.9, I was wrong the actual config is: ui.usehttp2, I'll clarify my post.

Comment: Well, that explains it! Mercurial 1.9 only came out 3 days ago :) So I was using the wrong version *and* the wrong name. I'll give it another try...

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! You just saved me hours of frustration. To anyone else, if you are seeing more than 100% while sending, you should seriously try usehttp2.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the repository you're pushing to doesn't support compressed transfer. What protocol are you using? If it's http, I recommend you watch the first requests to the remote repository (one of them is about determining the capabilities the remote repo offers).

If you're using a file URL for pushing, there's probably not much you can do about it.

Comment: I am pushing to Google Code using https. This line caught my attention: "capabilities: branchmap lookup unbundle=HG10UN,HG10UGZ,HG10BZ changegroupsubset" but I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: According to http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HttpCommandProtocol, this means that compression is supported. What happens when you push is you're pushing a bundle actually that gets merged into the remote repo. Can you try making a bundle of your full repository and see how big that is?

Comment: `hg bundle -a` generates a 35MB file. See the updated question, I've included an extract of the protocol negotiation.

Comment: @Gili: Sorry, I'm at a loss here. Probably best to forward this to the mercurial mailing list.